# how to align two image side by side (centre position) and text on them

Tags: html, css

so here is my question I am trying to align images like on this photo . so it is my piece of code

```
<body>
<div class="row" >
    <div class="column" >
        <img src="image/serviceimages/SVG/Asset 1.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column" >
        <img src="image/serviceimages/SVG/Asset 2.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row" >
    <div class="column" >
        <img src="image/serviceimages/SVG/Asset 3.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column" >
        <img src="image/serviceimages/SVG/Asset 4.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

it is a code without texts.

and there is my css what I have tried

```
.column {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
 
}
```

so the photos are under each other, not next each other so please any advice.

Comment: You can use flex concept of css for this. giving `display:flex;flex-direction:row;` to the parent tag

Comment: thank you. there are side by side. and the margin from the corner just make with margin left and right? or there is any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid was just made for this. See annotated markup below. Some good resources are as follows:

- [Learn grid the easy way](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU) from Kevin Powell
- [The complete guide to grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) at CSS tricks
- [Grid documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) on MDN
- [How to center in grid](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-center-a-div-using-css-grid-property/) on geeks for geeks
- [Containing blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) and 'position' on MDN

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* We want 2 columns, each are the same width */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* also make all rows the same height */
  width: 20ch; /* Set the overall width, delete this if you want it responsive */
}

.item {
  margin-inline: 6rem;  /* put a margin left and right so the black lines don't extend all the way to the end. */
  padding: 1rem; /* put some padding round each image */
  position: relative; /* Create a new containing block for the text */
  display: grid; /* Make the item a grid container so we can super-easy place the content right in the middle */
  place-items: center; /* does what it says */
}

.item:nth-child(n+3) { /* select the last 2 item elements */
  border-top: 2px solid black;  /* put a border on */
}

.text {
  position: absolute; /* make this absolutely positioned so it appears over the images */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: white;
  width: 75%; /* reduce the width to make it appear nicely over the image */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> <!-- we don't need rows and columns, just elements within the grid container, we use css to define how it lays out -->
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/41/200" alt="">
    <div class='text'>Digital Marketing Channel Audit</div> <!-- put the text in a div so we can center it -->
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/200" alt="">
    <div class='text'>Digital Marketing Strategy</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200" alt="">
    <div class='text'>Social Media Management</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/41/200" alt="">
    <div class='text'>Social Media Advertising</div>
</div>
```